# Trying to understand random access write versus sequential access writes

Tags: hard-drive, memory, operating-systems, storage

Say I create the text file on my Linux (or Windows) system, put some content and saved it. Will OS write it as random access writes (RW) or sequential access writes (SW). I understand the concept of RW and SW from [this blog post](https://insightsblog.violinsystems.com/blog/understanding-io-random-vs-sequential).

My understanding is to write above file, OS will first seek free block(which will be adjacent to last written block for any other file), write the content in in adjacent blocks. So per my understanding it is completely sequential access writes. Isn’t it ?

For reading the file I find it is mix of random and sequential read. Random read is because it can go to straight away go to that file block (instead of reading all blocks starting from first track) but once it reaches the right block, it will read complete file data sequentially as they are stored  in adjacent blocks

Then why hard disk is said to be random access writes or random reads instead of sequential writes/reads? Looks like I am missing something here in understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A disk drive is known as a random access device because it has this capability. This sets it apart from other devices, not too common, that require sequential access. This gives applications flexibility. Some files may be read or written entirely sequentially, others entirely randomly, others using a mixture. Text files are typically accessed sequentially but it doesn't have to be that way.

Comment: That's what I am trying to understand what use cases disk drive will/can actually use the random access writes and reads ?  To me logically  text files shuld always be written and read sequentially.

Comment: I can think of one case case where Random writes and reads can happen like RDBMS writes and reads.

Comment: Another need for accessing a text file randomly is in a text editor designed for very large files, often larger than memory. The program seeks to whatever portion of the file the user wishes to view or edit. Such editors were running on 8 bit computers in the 1980's, if not earlier. The need still exists. There are other situations.